# How to dynamically center image inside a smaller container?

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery slider, with random images from the forum. So, the size is pretty random but the gallery(container frame) itself is fix sized. So, we decided to set the image `height` to a fixed size but the `width` is set to auto. This way, the image will not be squeezed inside the container if its ratio different is too much from the container ratio.

Then, I set the container's `text-align` to center in order to center the image. But, this only works for images smaller than the container. If the image is still bigger than the container (after resize), the image is aligned to the left instead.

[The jsffidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/phelios/Cjamq/).

NOTE: Using background-image is not a solution because resizing background image currently is still not supported by many browsers (especially IE and some Chinese browsers).

Hope there is enough information here. So, how do I center the image in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I have found another solution

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width:600px; //set how much you want
        overflow: hidden; 
        position: relative;
     }
     .containerSecond{
        position: absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:-100%; 
        width:300%;
     }
     .image{
        width: 800px; //your image size 
     }           
</style>
```

and in body

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="containerSecond">
       <image src="..." class="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

This will center your image whenever your container is bigger or smaller. In this case your image should be bigger than 300% of container to not be centered, but in that case you can make with of containerSecond bigger, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You would use max sizes:

```
img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/fabianhjr/zW6eh/

Edit: still having centring problems, I will get back to you on that.

Comment: You're setting a width. In the question, it calls for a width set to auto.

Comment: No, it says he is having issues with the ratio.

Comment: If he is right then why did you say you wanted to have a width set to auto?

Comment: @MichaelRader I set it to auto so the ratio doesn't screw up (some images will seems squeezed if I fix the width) using max-width and max-height, it seems to be able to nicely resize the image regardless the ratio.

Comment: I'll help you with the v-align

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but the solution was about to crop right and left margin, while the image should be centered. Smaller images are stretched.

My solution is also in this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/david_binda/9tTRQ/

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumb-wrapper">
   <a href="" title="" class="img">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Tectonic_plate_boundaries.png" alt="" />    
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumb-wrapper{
    width: 200px; // desired thumbnail width
    height: 150px; // desired thumbnail height        
    overflow: hidden;    
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumb-wrapper .img{
    display: block;    
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; // should be wider than final thumbnail
    height: 150px; // desired thumbnail height
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px; // half of above defined width eg. 300/2 = 150
}
.thumb-wrapper .img img{
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 300px !important; // should be wider than final thumbnail
    min-width: 200px !important; // desired width of thumbnail
    height: 150px !important; // desired thumbnail height
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've found is:

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);//You have to add all the prefixes 
                                  //of transform
}
div.container{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I think this is your best solution.

You set your wrapper around each image to `display: table;` and then one more wrapper inside that with a `display: table-row;` and set your `img`'s to `display: table-cell`

This way you can resize anyway you like while keeping the ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/zW6eh/17/

You can also simply set your height: to 200px; This will keep your width auto by default.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid using min/max. Basically, only IE6 doesn't support it, and in that case it's the least of your worries. The `display:table` properties actually have less support.

Comment: @Madmartigan thats very true. should have thought of that.

Comment: I still have no clue what Phelios is trying to do, fairly vague question considering all the different ways this could be handled.

Comment: @Madmartigan Yeah took me several times reading it to understand what he wanted. I think I got it?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor constructed question. And thanks for the answer. Your jsfiddle fix seems to have irregular container size. The container supposed to be a fixed size. Only the image is resized to fit the container.

Comment: @Phelios sir, all you have to do is change the height or width of the container. A very simple fix. Please see updated fiddle, background color is to show container... http://jsfiddle.net/zW6eh/17/

Comment: @Phelios if you used this as your resolution, please award it as your answer. This is the best approach for your issue. Thank you.

Comment: @Phelios and if you used a different method, please post your answer so we know how it was resolved.

Comment: @MichaelRader hey, sorry, was busy with something else. I ended up using `margin: 0 25%` for the horizontal align instead of fixing the max-width. looks good on IE but still testing it on other browsers.